# UINavigationView in modal view

Tags: iphone

I would like to place a UINavigation View within a Modal view but I am having loads of problems. I managed to get the modal view working, but when trying to put a UINavigationController in it it just comes up with a blank screen.

Does anybody know how to do that properly?

Answer (score 2):

Create a `UINavigationController`, initialize it with your `UIViewController` at its root, and then present the *navigation controller* modally.