# how to present view model with navigation controller ? in object C

Tags: ios, objective-c

i know this question had been asked before but after few search i did not find an answer for my query here is the scenario  after presenting a view in a modally form the the simulator give me black screen as mentioned here:
[image: screen shot]

here is the code that i am using :

```
    NSString *username = self.usernameTf.text;
    NSString *password  = self.passwordTf.text;
    if ([username isEqualToString:@"zakaria"] || [password     isEqualToString:@"zakaria"]) {
        adminViewController *avc = [[adminViewController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *nav  = [[UINavigationController alloc]    initWithRootViewController:avc];
          [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

i already tried this solution [Modal View with Navigation Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479231/modal-view-with-navigation-controller)
but i got the same result any help guys

> Edited for given solution
>   i tried your solution but here is the result 
>   [image]  and here is the story board that i use

[image]

Comment: ***OR condition*** to check *username & password* is the ***most funniest*** part of this question...

Comment: Have you tried the solution I have provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok you are using storyboard. It means your view controller init does not create view. So you should give Storyboard Id to your adminViewController.
And then you should replace your adminViewController init

```
adminViewController *avc = [[adminViewController alloc] init];
```

With

```
adminViewController *avc =   [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"adminViewController"];
```

Then it should work fine.

But if you give storyboard id to your navigation controller you do not need to initialize any navigation controller. Storyboard will create both navigation and adminViewController.

[[image]]

Answer (score 0):

You have to first place the UINavigation Controller in the Storyboard just on the ViewController on which  you are calling this method

```
NSString *username = self.usernameTf.text;
        NSString *password  = self.passwordTf.text;
        if ([username isEqualToString:@"zakaria"] || [password     isEqualToString:@"zakaria"]) {
            adminViewController *avc = [[adminViewController alloc] init];

              [self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
```

Then all this work fine.

Answer (score 0):

All is fine... You need to make navigation controller as root of your design. Currently you have Login as root. As login is root, there is no navigation controller for your design and hence your code is not working.

*In-short, make navigation view controller as* ***Is Initial View Controller***

Even you don't need the below line in your code.

```
UINavigationController *nav  = [[UINavigationController alloc]    initWithRootViewController:avc];
```