# UIBackButtonItem Disappears when Presenting Modal View

Tags: ios, facebook, swrevealviewcontroller, fbsdksharekit

I want my app to share something in Facebook with this code. When I am done sharing or cancelled sharing. Then it returns to my ViewController embedded in a NavigationController.

The Back bar button item disappears(somehow hidden) but still functions on all View Controllers. ,

I am using SWRevealViewController.

This is my code to present the FB share dialog:

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentTitle = @"K&D Running App";
content.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl];
content.contentDescription = [self getStringPost];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:webUrl];
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController: self
                             withContent:content
                                delegate:nil];
```

Comment: FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init]; content.contentTitle = @"K&D Running App"; content.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]; content.contentDescription = [self getStringPost]; content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:webUrl]; [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController: self withContent:content delegate:nil];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modal View with Navigation Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479231/modal-view-with-navigation-controller)